# Incompatible types error joining a JavaPairRDD to JavaPairDStream using transform

Tags: java, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I'm trying to join a JavaPairRDD to RDD's in JavaPairDStream using transform but I'm getting the following error:

```
incompatible types: no instance(s) of type variable(s) W exist so that org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaPairRDD<java.lang.String,scala.Tuple2<LogType,W>> conforms to org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD<U>
```

Here's my code:

```
// Load full table from C*
JavaPairRDD<String,CassTableType> table = javaFunctions(
  jssc
).cassandraTable(
  "mykeyspace", "mytable", mapRowTo(CassTableType.class)
).keyBy(
  t -> t.getLogId()
);

// Process stream
JavaPairDStream<String,LogType> logs = flumeStream.flatMapToPair(
  flumeEvent -> { 
    List<Tuple2<String, LogType>> events = new LinkedList<>();
    LogType log = LogType.parse(flumeEvent);
    events.add(new Tuple2<String, LogType>(log.getLogID(), log));
    return events;
  }
);

// Join RDD's in logs DStream to table
JavaPairDStream<String, Tuple2<LogType, CassTableType>> 
  joinedRDD = logs.transform(
    rdd -> rdd.join(table))
);
```

Does it mean that rdd is `JavaRDD<U>` and not `JavaPairRDD<String,LogType>` as per the `JavaPairDStream<String,LogType>` I'm transforming? How do I achieve this join?

Answer (score 0):

Using transformToPair instead of transform solved it.